# Cannot ignore package in node_module when run test with Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I got this issue when setting up jest and run test although Jest was configured

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@momo-platform/component-kits/components/qrcodeScanner/QRCodeScannerView.js:1:2882)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@momo-platform/component-kits/index.js:1:22069)

  console.error node_modules/prop-types/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js:23
    Warning: Invalid arguments supplied to oneOf, expected an array, got 3 arguments. A common mistake is to write oneOf(x, y, z) instead of oneOf([x, y, z]).
```

This is config file jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'react-native',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    cacheDirectory: './cache',
    // "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    //   "./app/utils/vendor"
    // ],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            statements: 80,
        },
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '.+\\.(png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules\/(?!(react-native|react-native-camera-kit|react-native-linear-gradient|react-native-iphone-x-helper|react-native-progress|@react-native-community|@momo-platform/component-kits/components/qrcodeScanner/QRCodeScannerView.js))(.*)',
    ],
};
```

Could everyone help me to ignore issues of node_modules/@momo-platform/component-kits in node_module?

Comment: transformIgnorePatterns is to ignore transforms, as the name implies. It would be applicable if there were syntax error. Mock everything that is specific to native because it's not workable in Node.

Comment: So If I want to ignore Jest run-in  @momo-platform/component-kits How can I do that?

Comment: This error is Js not native code  TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

Comment: The package is specific to React Native, isn't it? You can be sure it fails because it was designed to run on a device and not in Node. As for ignoring, see https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks